# Port Forwarding Not Working in CENT OS 6.5 for SQUID Transparent Proxy

Tags: iptables, centos6, squid, portforwarding, transparentproxy

I am facing issues with Port forwarding in CENT OS 6.5.

i need to forward all incoming traffic from port 80 to 3128. like setting up a transparent proxy server. what ever i tried it didn't worked. My Transparent proxy server IP is 10.5.255.252

Please see my configuration below.

```
<code>
[root@xxxxxxhost xx-yy]# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             10.5.255.252        multiport dports http,https to:10.5.255.252:3128 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.5.0.0/16          anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

[root@xxxxxxhost xx-yy]# iptables-save
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [18:3530]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [9:540]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [228:14574]
-A PREROUTING -d 10.5.255.252/32 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.5.255.252:3128 
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.5.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT

[root@xxxxxxhost xx-yy]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
1

[root@xxxxxxhost xx-yy]# wget 127.0.0.1
--2014-03-12 04:05:51--  http://127.0.0.1/
Resolving 127.0.0.1... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to 127.0.0.1|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused.

[root@xxxxxxhost xx-yy]# wget 127.0.0.1:3128
--2014-03-12 04:05:55--  http://127.0.0.1:3128/
Resolving 127.0.0.1... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to 127.0.0.1|127.0.0.1|:3128... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ^C

[root@xxxxxxhost xx-yy]# 
</code>
```

if you see above the wget request to localhost on port 80 is refused, but the request for 3128 port is accepted. so its not working :(

Even tried the below rules.

```
<code>
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.5.255.252 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.5.255.252:3128
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.5.255.252 -p tcp --dport 3128 -j SNAT --to-source 10.5.255.252
</code>
```

But Nothing worked. Could you please help me to solve this.

Appreciate your help.